# Horizontal scrolling top menu iOS like instagram

Tags: scroll, menu, instagram, swipe

How to implement this menu? I want the best way to do that =)
The image of what I am saying...
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43484361/Arquivo%2018-06-15%2023%2015%2056.jpeg